# jQuery assign an input value to a hidden field when submit

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'd like to assign an input value to a hidden fold on submitting a form

```
<input name="fdata_ini" type="text" id="fdata_ini" value="123" />
```

this is the hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="fdata_ini_it" id="fdata_ini_it" value="" />
```

and the jQuery function

```
jQuery("form1").submit(function(){
  var ini_it;
  ini_it = jQuery("#fdata_ini").val();
  jQuery("#fdata_ini_it").val(ini_it);
})
```

but for me it does not work.

Comment: Your are not selecting your form properly. I assume form1 is your form id so use #form1 instead

Comment: Either your form has an ID of form1 and you need `$("#form1")` OR you need `$("form")` - voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._